# Replace ip tuntap by /etc/network/interfaces (or how to create a tun interface in /etc/network/interfaces)

Tags: networking, network-interface, iproute, tunneling

I'm using a sh script (pasted below) to create an IPv6 tun interface using iproute with the tun mode.

```
#!/bin/sh
# Create a new TUN interface for WPAN interaction.
ip -6 tuntap add mode tun tun0
# Assign it a global IPv6 address.
ip -6 addr add FF41::2 dev tun0
# Add route to default address of Serial TUN embedded interface.
ip -6 route add FF41::1 dev tun0
# Add route to Unique Local /64 Prefix via tun0.
ip -6 route add FF41:0000:0000:3EAD::/64 dev tun0
# The interface is ready.
ip link set tun0 up

# Enable IPv6 routing on host.
sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.all.forwarding=1
```

I would like to replace this script (that is called during startup) by a cleaner approach with `/etc/network/interfaces`, however, I'm a bit stuck as how to create this file exactly.

The command for the route addition, I know I will be replacing them with appropriate pre-up stanza in `/etc/network/interfaces`.
However, I'm not sure how to inform ifup that the interface to be created is a tun one.

Right now, my `/etc/network/interfaces` looks like this:

```
# 802.15.4 Network
auto tun0
iface tun0 inet6 static
    address FF41::2
    netmask 64
    pre-up ip -6 tuntap add mode tun tun0
    pre-up ip -6 route add FF41::1 dev tun0
    pre-up ip -6 route add FF41:0000:0000:3EAD::/64 dev tun0
    post-up sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.all.forwarding=1
```

On this device, I have a python script that uses pytun to link tun0 with a serial connection to an external device (that uses a 802.15.4 radio).

*EDIT:* It looks like I found a working solution using the above `interfaces` file. However, I'm still open to inputs regarding a more elegant solution (if there is one!). Thanks!